# How to initialize properties in ViewModel From events in IEventAggregator?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

If I have Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Events.IEventAggregator instance:

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEvent>.Subscribe(SomeMethod);
```

and I have a property in the ViewModel, and I want to initalize it using members in MyEvent class, how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Prism doesn't pass properties from `MyEvent` class to SomeMethod. It passes `payloads` as DTO:

```
public class MyEvent: CompositePresentationEvent<MyEventArgs> {}

public class MyEventArgs { int MyIntValue; }

public class Subscriber
{
  public Subscriber
  {
    eventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEvent>().Subscribe(SomeMethod);
  }

  public void SomeMethod(MyEventArgs e)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(e.MyIntValue);
  }
}

public class Publisher
{
  public void SendMinusOne()
  {
    var args = new MyEventArgs() { MyIntValue = -1 };
    eventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEvent>().Publish(args);
  }
}
```